# How to select from Dynamic entity in spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

In spring data, how to do somthing like

```
@Query("select code from :entityName where id= :id")
public String getGenicName(@Param("entityName") String entityName, @Param("id") String id)
```

to bind de name of entity dynamically, now I use :

String query = em.createQuery("select code from "+ entityName +" where id= "+ d).getSingleResult();

Thanks you

Comment: the question is unclear.

Comment: In spring data , how can i bind de name of entity dynamically, I use now

String query = 
em.createQuery(query.toString("select code from "+ entityName +" where id= "+:d).getSingleResult();

Thanks

Comment: You typically don't, because you want TypedQueries, and then you have to know the type a compile time. Maybe the problem you are trying to solve should not be solved by string concatenation (perhaps you should us CriteriaBuilder),, so I you described the actual problem we could tell you what the best (hopfully typesafe) solution is.

Comment: String query = em.createQuery("select code from "+ entityName +" where id= "+ d).getSingleResult();

It works very well but I want that my project does not import to the class of the other functional module (low-coupling), so I think to use the names of the class for the spring data query since we have the same spring context

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible by dynamically constructing the sql or jpql query string as you describe in your own comment:

```
em.createQuery("select code from "+ entityName +" where id= "+ d).getSingleResult();
```